# How to search through multiple sets with one linq statement

Tags: c#, linq

Consider three different lists of strings, one of which is a list of lists.  I need to search them all to find a particular one.

In this sample, the result is achieved, but I would like to do it in one Linq statement. Note that I do not want to change the existing collections, nor create any new ones.

```
        var collectionA = new List<string>() {"Item1", "Item2"};
        var collectionB = new List<string>() { "Item3", "Item4" };
        var listOfLists = new List<List<string>>() {new List<string>() {"Item5", "Item6"}, new List<string>(){ "Item7", "Item8"}};

        //Is there a better Linq way to do this?
        var searchString = "Item5";
        var item = collectionA.FirstOrDefault(i => i == searchString);
        if (item == null)
        {
            item = collectionB.FirstOrDefault(i => i == searchString);
            if (item == null)
            {
                foreach (var listOfList in listOfLists)
                {
                    item = listOfList.FirstOrDefault(i => i == searchString);
                    if (item != null)
                    {
                        break;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
```

Comment: I don't like your example, the `searchString` is also the `found result` if it's found in the collections? That doesn't make much sense, instead the result should be `bool` that means `is contained in or not`. Or you can modify your example so that you have collections of `Some Object`, it has some `Property` and we want to perform the search on that `Property`. That would make more sense.

Comment: I wrote the example that way for sake of simplicity.  In any case, your answer works perfectly with a slight change to FirstOrDefault instead of any.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
bool result = listOfLists.SelectMany(x => x)
                         .Concat(collectionA)
                         .Concat(collectionB)
                         .Any(x => x == "Item5");
```

Comment: Why a `bool` result?  And you missed listOfLists

Comment: @GregHollywood: please note that this answer also create the new collection which is not what you expected

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`SelectMany`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb534336.aspx) to flatten list of list, add `collectionA` and `collectionA` to `listOfLists` first:

```
 listOfLists.AddRange(new[] {collectionA, collectionB});

 if (listOfLists.SelectMany(x => x).Any(y => y == "Item5"))
 {
 }
```

With you new edit which does not prefer to change the existing collections, nor create the new one, you can do:

```
 if (listOfLists.Any(x => x.Any(y => y == "Item5"))
     || collectionA.Any(x => x == "Item5")
     || collectionB.Any(x => x == "Item5"))
 {
 }
```

Comment: I don't actually want to change the collection, nor create any new ones for performance reasons.

Answer (score 1):

```
var result = collectionA
    .Concat(collectionB)
    .Concat(listOfLists.SelectMany(i => i))
    .FirstOrDefault(i => i == searchString);
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this can help:

```
var collectionA = new List<string>() { "Item1", "Item2" };
var collectionB = new List<string>() { "Item3", "Item4" };
var listOfLists = new List<List<string>>() { new List<string>() { "Item5", "Item6" }, new    List<string>() { "Item7", "Item8" } };
var val = from y in (from x in listOfLists[0] select x) where y == "Item5" select y;
```

you can modify more to get your expected result